# How avoid that CSS animation's delay remove element from DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, styled-components

I have make some test here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mmo5nzyjvy

I have found that CSS animation's delay property remove my element from the DOM  until the element is animated.

I'm hence wondering how avoid that my element being removed from DOM while the delay is triggered?

any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put the animation effect on another class.

Once the animation is complete. remove the animating class from the animated elements.

Comment: I have to test it, I'm on other thing for now :)